# angular ngrx store update single property

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I'm using ngrx store with angular 6. I have an entity I'm updating with input boxes using ngModel binding. 
I update the state of the entity in the store at the change event of the Input calling an Update property action.
The update works fine and I can see the update is working.
Though, If possible I would like to make a general function that updates the state of the property by getting the binded property from the ngModel directive on the input control and passing it to the action. This way a general updating action can be possible.

Here is an illustrating code to show what I mean:
1) Follwing is the html of the component with the tagClip property binded:

```
<label>
  <input
    type="text"
    [ngModel]="tagClip"
    (change)="updateProperty($event)"> Include tag clip
</label>
```

2) At the component's ts back file is the updateProperty function:

```
updateProperty() {
    this.store.dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_PROPERTY
        payload: {
           // Following a dummy code to retrieve the binded property
           updatedProp: $event.target..ngModel.BindedProperty,   
           value: $event.value                                                       
        }
    });
 }
```

3) Finally the reducer code of the store will be as the following:

```
export function petTagReducer(state: PetTag = initialTag, action: Action)           
{
    switch (action.type) {
      case UPDATE_PROPERTY: {
          let newState = _cloneDeep(state);
          newState[updatedProp] = payload.value
          return newState
      }

      default:
       return state;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Chaim